# Immutable functions in latex3?

Tags: expl3, latex3

Imagine we have a nonempty sequence named `\l_tmpa_seq`. We want to assign a name `\l_tmpb_seq` a value which is the result of invoking a function like

```
\int_eval:n {#1 + 1}
```

on every member of the sequence.

**So take**

```
\seq_set_eq:Nx \l_tmpb_seq  { \l_process_cs:N \l_tmpa_seq }
```

where

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \l_process_cs:N #1 
{
    % Assign #1 to \l_name_seq
    % Process the sequence \l_name_seq
    % ...
    % Leave / return the sequence \l_name_seq
}
```

and (for brevity; might be a custom function instead)

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_eq:NN { Nx }
```

For now I resort to

1. mutating a second argument passed to such a function or
2. invoking `\seq_use:Nn \l_name_seq {some_delimiter}` as a `return` statement in an imperative language to serialize the result and invoking `\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_another_seq {#1} {some_delimiter}` as an assignment statement.

The first approach I would like to avoid completely, whereas the second is cumbersome but admits **syntactic constructs** like

```
\cs_return:N \l_name_seq
```

which could be done in a monadic fashion and

```
\seq_let:Nx \l_another_seq {\l_someFunction:N #1}
```

which I will implement to see how it works.

**How do you return, serialize, evaluate the result of a function when assigning it to a variable outside that scope?**

Comment: Isn't it `\seq_set_map:NNn`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! At the moment, I'm struggling to understand the question here: I think something like 'How do I arrange `\l_tmpb_seq` to contain the result of applying some function to each element of `\l_tmpa_seq`?' but I am far from certain. Could you perhaps add a 'non-programmers' explanation as most of us don't have formal backgrounds in the area!

Comment: @egreg I'd forgotten we had that one :-)

Comment: BTW, something like `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_eq:NN { Nx }` is definitely wrong as the base argument for `x` is `n`, whereas the only variant valid for `N` is `c`.

Comment: @egreg: Wow, I didn't look through the "Candidates" section of the manual (Sep 15, 2014). This may be exactly what I need.

Comment: @JosephWright: That's right. I was looking for a way to "assign" (define as the thunk/macro expansion) the result of applying a function to every element of a sequence -- which is a sequence -- as a value to another sequence. The only difference from the non-"Candidates" `map_function` and `map_inline` functions/macros should have been that we do not output ("leave in the output stream") the result of function applications but directly associate it with the name of another sequence, preferably succinctly.

Comment: @JosephWright: With regard to `\cs_genrate_variant:Nn`---thanks, I still haven't looked up the implementation of that function.

Comment: I notice I've mixed something up here in the comments. The question (the final sentence) is correct. The mapping facility was thought to be *implied* by a means to "return" a value from a function, thus *not* "exactly what I need" as it would solve just one issue. Besides, `seq_set_map:NNn` is limited to inline functions. As an attempt to clarify: Assume a language like Python, for simplicity. A typical assingment is `x = fn(arg)` where `x` is the name of some variable/object, `fn` a function, e.g., `def fn(z): return z` and `arg` the name of another variable/object.

Comment: @user74514 I think it's still not clear (but that might just be me). Please update the question so all the info is *in* the question, rather than in its comments. And, also, it's recommended to change your user name to something more informative than user01234.